# What is the difference between JeOS and minimal OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, suse, version

I see that recently a lot of Linux vendors are introducing JeOS version of their Operating System which by its definition and features looks to me like a minimal OS that has already been around for a lot of years. Is there any any difference between a minimal OS and JeOS ?

Example is Ubuntu which already had its minimal OS ISO's available from a long time has recently introduced Ubuntu JeOS. Also SUSE has it minimal OS version as well as JeOS

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any any difference between a minimal OS and JeOS?

Is there any difference between Ubuntu, SUSE, RedHat, Gentoo and ArchLinux?

Although they serve the same purpose they are different. While they *may* be almost identical feature-wise - and they will be rather similar in this aspect, because they *are* minimal, and the functionality overlap will grow as size decreases. Yet for users it matters, because they are used to something (e.g. RPM vs. deb packages) or the *infrastructure* offers some advantages - for example [SUSE Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Studio) might be an almost indispensable feature for some (I'm not aware of similar services for other distributions).

By the way, for example [Slax](http://www.slax.org) was providing its [modules](http://www.slax.org/en/modules.php) way before SUSE Studio ever existed.